# Memory alignment and padding in c

Tags: c

Consider this code segment

```
struct {
    short x[5];  
    union { 
        float y; 
        long z; 
    } u;
} t;
```

Assume that the objects of the type `short`, `float` and `long` occupy 2 bytes, 4 bytes and 8 bytes, respectively. The memory requirement for variable t, Don't ignore the alignment consideration, is:

My attempt without alignment consideration is that struct will reserve 10 bytes for x as each of size is 2 bytes and 8 bytes for long z therefore total would be equal to 18 bytes but I want to know more about what is this alignment?

Comment: I didn't get the question, you want us to clarify that 5 times 2 bytes is 10 bytes ?
In the meantime, alignment, and more importantly tools allowing you to inspect alignment easily (offsetof) are implementation dependant so it would be nice if you could confirm you're using gcc.

Comment: I want to know that what will be total memory used when we use memory alignment.

Comment: You can `printf("%d", sizeof(t));` in a sample program to figure out the total size of t.
Depending on your implementation, there should also be a way to find where the padding is without looking at memory's binary during runtime using "offsetoff" or something akin to that name.

Comment: and also I want to know about how this memory alignment work

Comment: @Alceste_ `printf("%d", sizeof(t));` --> `printf("%zu", sizeof(t));`

Comment: @4386427 He didn't provide his implementation and some were still not supporting it (%zu) last time I checked.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know about how this memory alignment work

From the C standard:

> **alignment**
>
> requirement that objects of a particular type be located on storage boundaries with
> addresses that are particular multiples of a byte address

and further

> **Alignment of objects**
>
> Complete object types have alignment requirements which place restrictions on the
> addresses at which objects of that type may be allocated. An alignment is an
> implementation-defined integer value representing the number of bytes between
> successive addresses at which a given object can be allocated. An object type imposes an
> alignment requirement on every object of that type

Notice the part: implementation-defined

So an implementation of the C-standard is allowed to specify restrictions on the addresses where an object of a specific type may be located.

For instance, it could be that `float` should always be placed at addresses that are multiples of 8, i.e. valid addresses would be X * 8. So 4000, 4008, 4016 would be valid while 4001, 4002, 4003, 4004, 4005, 4006, 4007 would be invalid.

For such implementations padding will be inserted into structs in order to get a valid address.

For your example:

If your compiler requires 8-bytes alignment of `long`, it will have to insert padding between `x` and `z` to make `z` start at an 8 byte aligned address. The size will then be 24 bytes.

But remember that this is implementation defined.

You can try this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
struct { 
    short x[5];  
    union { 
        float y; 
        long z; 
    } u;
}t;
 
int main(void) {
    printf("Size of t     is %zu\n", sizeof(t));
    printf("Size of t.x   is %zu\n", sizeof(t.x));
    printf("Size of t.u.y is %zu\n", sizeof(t.u.y));
    printf("Size of t.u.z is %zu\n", sizeof(t.u.z));
    printf("Location of t   is %p\n", (void*)&t);
    printf("Location of t.x is %p\n", (void*)t.x);
    printf("Location of t.y is %p\n", (void*)&t.u.y);
    printf("Location of t.z is %p\n", (void*)&t.u.z);
    return 0;
}
```

Possible output:

```
Size of t     is 24
Size of t.x   is 10
Size of t.u.y is 4
Size of t.u.z is 8
Location of t   is 0x559b60552020
Location of t.x is 0x559b60552020
Location of t.y is 0x559b60552030
Location of t.z is 0x559b60552030
```

Notice here that the size of `t.x` is 10 but the address distance between `t.x` and `t.y` is 16 (aka 0x10) so there are 6 bytes padding between `t.x` and `t.z`.

Answer (score 0):

> therefore total would be equal to 18 bytes but i want to know more about what is this alignment?

I am a compiler. I assume from your post that:

- type - size and alignment
- `short` - 2 bytes
- `float` - 4 bytes
- `long` - 8 bytes

So I have this code:

```
struct {
    short x[5];    // 2 * 5 = 10 bytes, has to start at address divisible by 2
    union { 
        float y;   // 4 bytes, has to start at address divisible by 4
        long z;    // 8 bytes, has to start at address divisible by 8
    } u; // an union, so we take bigger address and alignment..
         // so it will have 8 bytes, but it also has to start at address
         // divisible by 8
} t; // a structure, I need to take the biggest alignment requirement of members
     // so it has to start at address dividable by 8
     // and it has at least the size of sum of members
     // so at least 10 + 8 bytes + padding
```

So because `_Alignof(long) = 8`, I'll make `typeof(t)` start at address divisible by 8. So I'll look at my linker script and pick... and pick for example memory address 200.

But `u` needs to start at address divisible by 8. So:

```
 struct {         // memory cell 200
     short x[5];  // 12 half-words in memory cells 200 - 211 
                  // (211 inclusice, 212 exclusive)
     // 212 % 8 = 4, so we need to insert 4 bytes padding here
     // so that union will start at address divisible by 8
     // padding 4 bytes, memory cells 212 - 215
     union {      // long-word in memory cells 216 - 223
                  // 216 is divisible by 8
        float y;   // word in memory cells 216 - 219
        long z;    // long-word in memory cells 216 - 223
     } u;
 } y; // so it has size of 12 + 4 bytes padding + 8 = 24 bytes
```

Alignment is just that the variable has to start at memory address that is divisible by a number. So you insert padding between members, so that they start at address divisible by a number they need to.